# How can I change the layout of eclipse workspace selection dialog?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I want to add a more options (eg: radio button) to the workspace dialog so that when I launch workspace preference/properties are already set. In short I want to include a set of preferences along with workspace location while launching eclipse application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dialog is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog`. It does not support any customization and because it is an internal dialog you should not use it in your code.

So it is not possible to change this without breaking the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html)

You can set default preferences in the `plugin_customization.ini` file in the `plugins/org.eclipse.sdk_xxx` directory in your Eclipse install (this applies to all workspaces).

Comment: Thnx for reply.. :).. Will look into what u suggested